# PHP $_SESSION variables not renewing on page template

Tags: php, variables, session

Page A and Page B both use PHP page template 1, which is storing `get_the_title();` in `$_SESSION['pagesource'] = get_the_title();` and sending it to another php file.

However, after visiting page A, then going to page B the variable stills shows the `pagesource` for Page A until I refresh the page. How do I clear the session so the `$_SESSION['pagesource']` is available and true for both pages?

I'm using `session_start();` on both pages

Thanks

Comment: Are you using/have you tried [`session_unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)? Also, could you give us a little bit of your code, that is relevant?

Comment: I tried session_destroy in the footer which killed the variable data completely. How would I use unset?

Comment: So am I right in thinking that on page B you want to completely clear the `$_SESSION['pagesource']` variable, and set it anew @MikeJackson?

Comment: Indeed @joe_young, and the first time I visit Page B, as currently they only renew when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, at the top of Page B (or indeed any page)

```
<?php
    //Remember to start the session on each page
        session_start();
    //Unsets all session variables without discretion - ony use if strictly necessary
        session_unset(); 
    //Destroys the session, again without discretion - ony use if strictly necessary
        session_destroy();
    //Typical way to unset any variable
        unset($_SESSION['pagesource']);

    //Create a new $_SESSION['pagesource'] session variable and set it equal to what get_the_page_title() returns
        $_SESSION['pagesource'] = get_the_page_title();
        //do anything you want with the page title
    exit();
?>
```

I am very much covering all bases there; try this and if if works we can work on refining it

Comment: That was it! Ok so the only part I actually needed was `unset($_SESSION['pagesource']);` after `session_start()`Brilliant answer. Thank you.

Comment: That's great! I'm glad to have been of help @MikeJackson